# How can I make hidden files display in Eclipse Project explorer when using a RSE linked folder?

Tags: eclipse

So in my project i link a folder with Remote Systems Explorer.  I have some hidden files I need to edit like .htaccess

**What I tried**

- removed .* filter from Project
- explorer windows checked "show hidden
  files" in RSE properties

Still doesn't display the hidden files for me

Any light to shed ?

Comment: removing the mentioned filter works for me.. of course im using PDT and im on a Mac so i might have to do with the type of project/perspective youre using.

Answer (score 36):

Eclipse (Helios) shows hidden files in the "Navigator" view. You can add that via **Window** --> **Show View** --> **Navigator**.

Comment: The Navigator is now marked as `(deprecated)` in newer eclipse versions (e.g. 2019-12).

Comment: Even though the Navigator is marked `(Deprecated)` in Eclipse Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0), it still works to show hidden files (files beginning with `.` in Linux), whereas the Project Explorer does not show them. Pretty dumb that I can't make the Project Explorer show them.

Answer (score 32):

In eclipse 2019-06 version, **Project Explorer** shows "**View Menu**" option (down arrow) at the right side. Click on it and then click on "**Filter and Customization**", then uncheck ".*resources" option in the "**Pre-set filters**" tab.

Answer (score 15):

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Remote Systems -> Files:
Check the "Show hidden files" 
Ok.

Answer (score 7):

Windows -> Navigation -> Show View Menu -> Filters, then uncheck ". * resources"

Eclipse version 2020-03 (4.15.0)

Comment: This seems to be the the right answer for a different purpose i.e. local project folders

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1).  Window -> Preferences -> Remote Systems (on left menu area) -> Files -> Check "Show Hidden Files".

Answer (score 1):

easiest way to show hidden files on eclipse (using mac os) 
first you need to show hidden options on the system in the first place 
follow this [post](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-funter-macos-sierra-3520878/)

then all you need to do is to open finder drag the wanted folder into the quick access navigation bar (on the left of the finder window) .

Answer (score 1):

For 2019 versions there is a filter icon top left. There you can define which files should be hidden from user.

Comment: This solved it for me in Eclipse Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0), Build id: 20201210-1552

Comment: 2021-09 as well

Answer (score 0):

Works for STS 4(V. 4.17.2.RELEASE)

(in Project Explorer pane) 'select a project or any sub-node' >

[Window] > [Navigation] > [Show View Menu] > [Filters and Customization...] > '**UN**check [.*resources]'